# Email server with in/out monitor and backup functionalities?

Tags: email, mail-server

How could a company trace of all incoming and outcoming message linked to its corporate emails ?

This would be convenient to audit some inboxes in case of an conflict where email exchanges are involved.
Today we use OVH emails and we cannot log outgoing emails or access received emails if they are deleted.

Is there a solution ?

Regards

Comment: You mean something like the `bigbrother` option from  http://www.lifewithqmail.org/ldap/ `Folr ISP that need to implement some surveillance method because of some beloved authorities...`?

Comment: I believe this question is more suited for superuser stackexchange.

Comment: How is this question connected to programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i understand the question fully but if you mean "Is there a reach enterprise mail solution?" then yes there is.
My favourite is [Apache James](https://james.apache.org/) (open source).

Depending on your workload (how much traffic your company has, what consistency you should have, what features are required) you need to spend some time to configure it properly.

You can make a simple proxy to trace your emails or you can make some process which will process all stored emails (in Cassandra or PostgreSQL or any storage you are willing to choose).

You also asked about backup functionalities. As you can choose from a wide variety of storages you can use backup functionalities for such storages (For [Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupRestore.html), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/backup-dump.html) or anything you use as a storage). Also, most of those storages support replication to ensure your data is safe.